# how to save google map polygon coordinates in database using DbGeography in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have implemented google map draw polygon as per below link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

on "polygoncomplete" event, I called below function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
            var polygonPoints = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
                var lat = polygon.getPath().getAt(i).lat();
                var lng = polygon.getPath().getAt(i).lng();
                polygonPoints.push({ lat: lat, lng: lng })
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(polygonPoints));

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "@Url.Action("onPolygonComplete", "Utility")",
                data: JSON.stringify(polygonPoints),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (resultResponse) {
                    console.log(resultResponse)
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            });
        });
```

which prepares polygon points JSON and saves polygon coordinate in database using DbGeography (e.g: DbGeography.PolygonFromText(polygonWkt, 4326))

While drawing polygon on India or it's near by location, it saved successfully but when drawn a polygon in China or U.S.A, it throws below errors:

1. The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance
   because it exceeds a single hemisphere. Each geography instance must
   fit inside a single hemisphere. A common reason for this error is
   that a polygon has the wrong ring orientation
2. Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.

so how can i save polygon coordinates in database using DbGeography.PolygonFromText() function

Comment: Can you please show the data that you arepassing

Comment: System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography.PolygonFromText("POLYGON((127.652 -26.244,127.652 -26.194,[some other points],127.652 -26.244))", 4326);

show detail from: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/65495

Comment: check this: https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/ring-orientation-bigger-than-a-hemisphere-polygons-and-the-reorientobject-method-in-sql-server-2012/